# Flexbox item widths are affected by padding

Tags: css, flexbox

See http://jsfiddle.net/56qwuz6o/3/:

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
</div>

div div {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

When I have padding set on a flex item (`#a`), its width (in the `border-box` sense) is affected.  How do I make its computed width ignore the padding?  ie. I want each of my boxes to take up 33% of the document width.

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers so far.  But in reality, I actually have more boxes in the row that have a fixed width: ie. at http://jsfiddle.net/56qwuz6o/7/, I want `#a`, `#b` and `#c` to all have the same width.

```
<div style="display:flex; width: 400px">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    <div id="d">d</div>
</div>

div div {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
    padding-right: 100px;
}

#d {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 option you have is to set `flex-basis: 33.33%` or a number relative to the amount of children you have. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it dynamically.

Comment: This makes sense as a workaround, but is this behavior of flexbox to add size to an element when using padding, even when you have `box-sizing: border-box;` specified, part of the spec or is it just an implementation bug in flexbox?

Comment: Neither box-sizing mode is helping. (current Chrome, June 2018).

Answer (score 9):

A proper `flex: declartion seems to work.

```css
div div {

  flex: 0 0 33%; 
  /* don't grow, don't shrink, be 33% wide */
  /* flex:1 0 33% works too */
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

#a {

  padding-right: 100px;

}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It works for the example I gave, but my actual situation is a bit more complicated.  See the updated question.

Comment: Please don't change questions once answers have been given, **especially** if they invalidate the answers already given. Create a ***new** question and link back to the old one.

Answer (score 5):

As a broader answer to the problem: All of `padding`, `border`, `margin` appear to be fix deductions of the available total width, before remaining space is divided up within flex-box. Thus, boxes with more padding will in effect gain more space. Best demonstrated with two flex below each other, one with a double column:

(the table as it should be. Bad things applio below ↓)

[image]

#### [→ Codepen.](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/oyGzoY?editors=1100)

```
section
  display: flex
  width: 90%

  div   
    flex: 1 1 100%
    background: #aca
    // good to illustrate boundaries, since it has no width effect…
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 6px rgba(black, .4)
    
  .double
    flex: 2 1 200%
```

**Notes**:

`auto` as flex-basis (the 3rd `flex:` parameter) is bad, because it looks at actual content. You don't the amount of content make your layout shift. (compare: [`table-layout: auto`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)). Go with `100%`. (Even if that adds up to many hundred percents total.)

ALL of the following will destroy above grid alignment:

```
border: 8px solid orange
padding-left: 8px
margin-left: 8px
```

And no, neither value for `box-sizing` will help against this.

#### →The best way to pad flex boxes in a given grid is an inner tag (i.e. one with full width and padding).

Answer (score 0):

Create Flexbox Styles to make the development process faster

```
<style>
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  }

  .flexSize-1 {
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
  }
  .flexSize-1 {
    flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
  }
</style>
```

As long as the `flex` property is equal for each column, then each column will get be equal size accross the window.

```
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flexSize-1">
      <h1 class="page-header">Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flexSize-1">
      <h1 class="page-header">Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flexSize-1">
      <h1 class="page-header">Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

if you ever want 1 column to be larger than another column, give that column the class `.flexSize-2` and it will be twice as wide as `.flexSize-1`

Comment: He's after an answer that creates equal column when some items have padding. This is just equal columns with equal styles on each child