# Why don't the three child elements have the same size even though they have the flex: 1 property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make three children, which are not the same type of HTML element, have equal widths. However, when I apply the same property to them, the one that is not inside a div (the button) has more width than the other two elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padre {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.hijo {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">
    <button>child 1 </button>
  </div>
  <button class="hijo">child 2</button>
  <div class="hijo">child 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe. They all have the same width according to the inspector

Comment: The first and last divs measure approximately 61, while the middle button measures 76. All three direct children of the parent have the property flex: 1 applied. However, they do not have the same width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox item widths are affected by padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099624/flexbox-item-widths-are-affected-by-padding)

Comment: As shown in the link, either wrap the button in a div, or use `flex-basis:33%` if you know there is only 3 items. You could also use `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they have the same size, you can see the exact sizes with Chrome's dev tools.

What happens:

The div have exactly 1/3 of total parent's width, but the button's width adjust to fit its contents.

```
<div class="hijo">
    <button>child 1 </button>
 </div>
```

In this case, the button receive the flex value, so it adjust self to 100% of 1/3.

```
<button class="hijo">child 2</button>
```

Lastly, this div have 1/3 too, but no style that can help us see it. If you set a background-color to it, you'll understand.

```
<div class="hijo">child 3</div>
```

Comment: I partially agree. Because even though they measure the same, flex does not include the padding and border of the second child in the calculation of the available space, making it different. I might be wrong, though.